# Django Performance why is there a huge time gap between the total time and SQL time

Tags: django, django-views

So, I have a big issue with how long it takes to load my page on the development server.  Believe it or not, for one of the pages on the site, it currently takes about a minute to load according to Django's debug toolbar while the toolbar shows SQL time of roughly 1 second (still too long).  So, why is there such a gap.  I tried loading on other pages that loads the same overhead, e.g. static files like js, fonts, pictures, etc. and they are no where close (around 2-3 seconds).

I am using a DetailView and adding some related data to the request using get_context_data.  So, I have timed each method call.  Here are some more detailed numbers on performance:

```
The get request took:  9.8e-06
The get request took:  9.200000000000007e-06
The get_object call took:  0.0642546
The get_object call took:  0.0660097
The get_object call took:  0.0505043
The get_object call took:  0.048121899999999995
The entire get_context_data took:  1.6127981
The entire get_context_data took:  1.6103409999999998
```

Notice that each is called twice with the exception of get_object which was called four times!

Comparing page to page, I cannot figure out why it takes so long for this page to load vs another page with the same overhead (e.g. static files such as js, css, images, fonts, etc.)

I'd appreciate some insight into this.

Comment: Hard to say exactly what you're running into but a couple of things I would look into are: What db are you using and how are you handling db connections? Are you creating a new db connection for every call to the database or every request and for some reason that connection creation is taking a long time? I don't think establishing the db connection is included in the debug toolbar timing. Are you using `select_related` and `prefetch_related` to reduce the number of db calls?

Comment: I am using select_related on my queries but not prefetch_related. Also, I am not quite sure how to find out the number of db connections. I am using Postgres DBMS

Comment: Was there any resolution on this?  I am trying to track down the exact same issue.

Comment: Well, I suspect that the view function ran fine, but the template rendering took a long time.  Templates are tricky to work with since they may take long and add additional database hits. For that reason, it is better to use Django Rest Framework or only pass non-objects to the templates (e.g. strings and numbers)